# Unbalanced and missing data in generalized mixed effects model

Tags: missing-data, unbalanced-classes, observational-study

I have a highly unbalanced dataset from observational data. I want to assess sources of variation on my dependent variable (Y, binomial distribution), controlling by the year of sampling. For that, I am thinking to use a generalized linear mixed-effects model including Year as a random effect, and two class variables (A and B) with two levels each (e.g. A1 and A2) as fixed effects, the model would look something like this:

```
Y = A + B + (1|Year)
```

Looking at my data, the levels of my predictors are not well represented in all years, including missing observations in some of them. This is the table of observations:

| Observations | 2000 | 2001 | 2002 | 2003 | 2004 | 2005 | 2006 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | 13 | 7 | 0 | 5 | 50 | 40 | 2 |
| A2 | 0 | 20 | 10 | 15 | 0 | 40 | 35 |
| B1 | 5 | 10 | 4 | 7 | 10 | 8 | 1 |
| B2 | 8 | 17 | 6 | 13 | 40 | 72 | 36 |

I have got interesting results, however, I know Year could be an important variation source, and for variable A not all the levels are represented in some years (see A2 in 2000 or A1 in 2002). How well the GLMM deals with such an unbalanced data? Is it reliable to use a logistic regression when there are missing observations like the ones I highlight here?
Thanks in advance!